# Importando um arquivo .sql muito grande

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Tenho um arquivo com cerca de 192,2 MB de tamanho. Tentei importa-lo pelo PHPMyAdmin, mas ele reclama que o arquivo é grande demais. Procurei pela internet uma possível solução para o caso, e vi que tem que ser através do "source"

exemplo:

```
mysql > source: nomeDoArquivo.sql
```

Fiz exatamente desta forma mas ele sempre me retorna erro.

```
Failed to open file 'cep_mysql.sql', error: 2
```

Alguém sabe alguma forma de eu fazer isto? 
Fiz errado é necessário por o arquivo em algum diretório especifico?
Grato!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem algumas formas de importar dados para o MySQL. 
Pela sua necessidade, e como aparentemente possui acesso a executar comandos em um cliente capaz de se conectar ao servidor, creio que seja mais adequado o seguinte modelo:

No diretório onde se encontra seu arquivo de instruções SQL, digite:

```
mysql -u NOME_USUARIO -h HOST -p NOME_BASE_DADOS < arquivo.sql
```

Será requisitado a senha de conexão.

Outras formas de importar dados de um arquivo SQL podem ser encontradas aqui

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-batch-commands.html